# Why is my Holo Light app blurry and blown up?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I am just learning to program Android apps and am using Netbeans. My main.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <EditText android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that it looks blurry and the UI elements are really big. I'm running it on a 7 inch tablet and it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO22M.png

Can I fix this?

Comment: weight in edittext seems fishy... Try removing it.

Comment: Have you got the same problem with `Portrait` mode?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the *handset* size layout for a 7 inches screen which results bitmap scaling and blurry layout. Have you used *Size Qualifier* to support different screen size?

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

Take a look at this: [`Supporting Multiple Screens`](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#ConfigurationExamples)